# calculate the orientation of a blob

Tags: c++, orientation, blob, ellipsis

[image]

I have an image with a white blob as visualized in the attached picture. I would like to calculate the 'orientation' of it. Imagine the blob being located in a coordinate system with x- and y-axis. I can calculate the centroid by adding all the white pixels coordinates and dividing by the sum of all white pixels but to get the orientation (which I marked with the red line) I would hav to find some extreme point or something like that.

This would somehow relate to the problem of positioning an ellipsis in this system although so far I haven't found anything on that problem either.

Anyone have any clues?

Comment: I would guess you could use PCA to find the principal axes of the blob and take your orientation from that.

Comment: Where is the picture?

Comment: Or if not PCA, perhaps calculate orientation simplistically by determining the angle from the centre of gravity of the blob to the furthest point from that centre along the blob's perimeter?

Comment: Least squares regression line.

Comment: hey, thanks for your quick reply. I was thinking of the same thing, sometimes though, the furthest point away does not resemble the extreme of the blob. For those cases, in which it does though, it should work.

Comment: will look into lsrl, thanks for that hint!

Comment: Find the two points that have the biggest distance from each other and draw a line between them

Comment: thanks for your inpuit, hermione, unfortunately I wasnt completely clear - there are situations, where the two extreme points are not creating the desired axis!

Comment: Do you prefer accuracy or speed?

Comment: You are asking a statistics problem, not a programming question - voting to close as off topic.

Comment: actually both, preferrably speed. should be able to run nect to other optimization problems in real time. I besides think, this is a programming question since I am looking for feasible algorithms to handle this but please, do as you think.

Answer (score 0):

a thinning algorithm, or even a medial axis transform, to get a one pixel sequence of points and then select the most distant points between those to find the line with the right orientation